# How can I read a file present at the installation folder of my optional package

Tags: msix

I have added a file as part of an optional package, which is consumed by a main C# application. When I try to read that file which is present at

C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\`<Package_Name_Etc>`\`search.config`

```cs
using (Stream reader = new FileStream(Path.Combine(_directory,"search.config"), FileMode.Open))
```

I get an error of `System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\<Package_Name_Etc>\search.config' is denied.'`

I fail to understand why the code of optional package doesn't have access to this file.

Answer (score 0):

It might fail because you are using **FileMode.Open**, which has by default read/write access.

Try setting [FileAccess to read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileaccess?view=net-6.0).

The files from the installation folder of an MSIX package are read-only. Apps that try to load them while requesting write permissions will fail. If you want to write something in the config file you should create a copy of the file in the AppData folder, the first time your application is launched, and edit that copy of the file.